# How do I define a TypeScript interface for an empty array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This interface describes my answers array (IActivityAnswer[]).

```
export interface IActivityAnswer {
  createdAt: string;
  id: string;
  questionId: string;
  score: number;
  summary: string;
  title: string;
  commentCount?: number;
}
```

Some users won't have any answers (so they will have an empty array). How do I define a type for empty array. I want to accomplish this without using type any.

Comment: What type would you like the array to have? How do you plan on using it?

Comment: If you're not going to store anything in it, why have that array anyway?

Comment: What's the sense of this question?

Comment: @TomFenech 

This interface describes the populated array:

export interface IActivityAnswer {
  createdAt: string;
  id: string;
  questionId: string;
  score: number;
  summary: string;
  title: string;
  commentCount?: number;
}

I make an api call to get data. While the api call is pending the array is empty.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  For best results, please review the documentation on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what constitutes a [mcve].

Comment: An [array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array) like `IActivityAnswer[]` can represent an array of any number of `IActivityAnswer` elements, including zero.  Perhaps that's all you need, unless you have a use case that requires that you know *at compile time* that an array is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure how much benefit you will get from defining an empty array since you will have to do a union type, i.e. `EmptyArray | IActivityAnswer[]`. This means that you may have to handle the types separately for anything that operates them. Generally speaking, the `IActivityAnswer[]` type could be empty and you could still operate on it as you would any other array. Using `.map` would just return another empty array, for example.

Answer (score 9):

As of TypeScript 3.0, you can use the empty tuple type, written `[]`.

```
const empty: [] = [];
```

However, even without this feature, I don't understand why you would need to use `any` since you could write something like

```
const empty = <never[] & {length: 0}>[];
```

The empty tuple type `[]` should be preferred as it provides more robust checking and better error messages when misused.

Comment: Any thoughts on the case where the array is both defined with a type interface, but sometimes there will be no items in the array?

Comment: Your second declaration throws `Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts sorry, I forgot that strict type checking would disallow the assignment from the literal `[]`. A type assertion is required. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: another format is: `const answerArray : Array<IActivityAnswer> = [ ];`

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `IActivityAnswer[]` and the type would be defined as the following:

> An array containing IActivityAnswer objects, or an array not containing IActivityAnswer objects, i.e. an empty array.